# Connecting from Docker container to WSL2 physical machine

Tags: docker, networking

We're currently working on porting a stack of NET 4.7 projects to Linux/Docker. Since we're doing it one project at a time, there needs to be network connectivity between Windows projects running on physical machine and Linux projects running in WSL2/Docker.
Currently I'm using the external IP of the physical machine, but I'm not sure whether Docker in this case takes some external path (or any firewall) to get from inside WSL2 and container to external IP of it's parent host.